# Does shake have an equivalent to make's dry-run option?

Tags: shake-build-system

The `make` utility lets you see what would be built, without actually building it, by using the command-line option `--dry-run`. Does `shake` have something equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

The output of the `--help` flag suggests

```
--no-build                  Don't build anything.
```

is what what you want.

Comment: No build just builds nothing, it doesn't tell you what it would have built, so it's not quite the same.

Comment: Oh I see.  My bad.

Answer (score 2):

No, Shake doesn't have an equivalent, but there's a feature request for it at https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/172. It's not as simple in Shake since which rules are run can depend on the output of previous rules, but I have some ideas of how it could be implemented.

There is a --no-command flag which just skips running `command`/`cmd` things, which is sometimes sufficient for very specific use cases (but not usually).